# raindrops - downward velocity antiderivative question

Tags: integration

### I am working through an antiderivative question but there is one part of the answer I don't understand.

Since raindrops grow as they fall, their surface area increases and therefore the resistance to their falling increases. A raindrop has an initial downward velocity of 10  and its downward acceleration is

$$
a=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
9-0.9 t & \text { if } 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 10 \\
0 & \text { if } t>10
\end{array}\right.
$$

If the raindrop is initially 500  above the ground, how long does it take to fall?

So,
$$
v(t)=-9 t+.45 t^{2}-10
$$
$$
s(t)=-4.5 t^{2}+.15 t^{3}-10 t+500
$$

And then punch in t=10
$$
s(10)=-4.5(10)^{2}+.15(10)-10(10)+500=100
$$

It's the position result of a 100 I don't undertand. What is the 100 supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s(t)$ is a function which denotes the position of raindrops at time $t.$ When $t = 0,$ then $s(0) = 500.$ This tells us that the raindrops start falling at $500$ units. We find their position at $10$ seconds when $t = 10,$ which we see is $s(10) = 100.$ This tells us that at $10$ seconds, the raindrops are $100$ units above $0.$ However, the question of

> If the raindrop is initially 500 above the ground, how long does it take to fall?

was not answered. If you would like to answer this question, then you need to set $s(t) = 0$ and solve for $t.$ This is a standard quadratic equation.

Comment: So a non-zero result from the position function s(t) is basically the amount the object is short of hitting the ground at 0.  Is that right?

Comment: That is one way to look at it, yes.